# Integration of 0X (payments and router)

Tags: transactions, 0x, router

Two questions for the team of 0x.org

- Can we connect our own router to your system? (same as apeswap and cafeswap did)
- Can we somehow take payment for the transactions in our coin, not in yours? (everything will be on BSC)

Comment: Gotcha, sorry, I deleted my previous comment. Let's delete these other too as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer you'll find in our DM on Discord, but I'd like to put it here for posterity:

You can find more about consuming liquidity surfaced by our `/orderbook` endpoint here: https://0x.org/docs/api#orderbook, https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/orders.html#limit-orders, https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/functions.html#filllimitorder. If you're having more specific issues with your integration, please put them up on StackExchange in as much detail as possible and we'll provide further technical help

In terms of taking other liquidity, you can also surface liquidity through our `/swap` endpoint: https://0x.org/docs/api#swap.

Taking fees in anything other than the native token is not supported by the 0x API at this time.